How to replace unicode displaying in XML from SQL results
I have the following SQL query that (appears to have some kind of whitespace at the end)is returning data in my XML output and I am trying to remove this upfront in the SQL from being shown in the XML output:
SELECT 'H' KEY , 
REPLACE(REPLACE(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, CHR(8237), ''), CHR(8236), '') vendor_catalog_number

FROM MyTable

SQL results (doesn't appear to show the whitespace at the end):
KEY        vendor_catalog_number
H       ‭   ‭CUR251636‬


XML output:
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>
<DATA_DS>
<G_1>
<KEY>H</KEY>
<VENDOR_CATALOG_NUMBER><0x202d>‭CUR251636‬<0x202c></VENDOR_CATALOG_NUMBER>
</G_1>
</DATA_DS>

As a result the data is being rendered in my Oracle eText report template as ?CUR251636?
(with the question marks around the string.)
I also tried using just for Linefeeds and Carriage returns as below but that still did not work:
REPLACE(REPLACE(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, CHR(13)), CHR(10)) vendor_catalog_number

What other Oracle SQL function can I use to remove this whitespace/unicode characters?
EDIT:
SELECT DUMP(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, 1016) FROM MyTable

Results:  Typ=1 Len=15 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: e2,80,ad,43,55,52,32,35,31,36,33,36,e2,80,ac
SELECT DUMP(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, 1016) FROM MyTable

Results: E280AD435552323531363336E280AC

Please provide more information about the values in MyTable:
SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM) FROM MyTable

@ValentinTabacaru The value when using UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW is: E280AD435552323531363336E280AC

What data type is the column, and what are your database and national character sets? SELECT DUMP(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, 1016) FROM MyTable might also be helpful - please add the output of that and the previous query to the question as an edit, not a comment.

@AlexPoole the datatype of this column is VARCHAR2. Here is the result of what your asking for above:  Typ=1 Len=15 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: e2,80,ad,43,55,52,32,35,31,36,33,36,e2,80,ac

Those are POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING and LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE. No idea why they are there; perhaps from some conversion between writing systems on insert?
Anyway... it seems you need the AL16UTF16 version of the codepoints, not the AL32UTF8 versions (not sure why, hopefully someone else can explain it...). Your code with CHR() doesn't replace anything:
with cte as (
  SELECT 'H' KEY,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, CHR(8237), ''), CHR(8236), '') vendor_catalog_number
  FROM MyTable LN
)
select KEY, vendor_catalog_number,
  DUMP(vendor_catalog_number, 1016) as dmp,
  RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(vendor_catalog_number)) as hex
from cte




KEY
VENDOR_CATALOG_NUMBER
DMP
HEX




H
‭CUR251636‬
Typ=1 Len=15 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: e2,80,ad,43,55,52,32,35,31,36,33,36,e2,80,ac
E280AD435552323531363336E280AC



If you use the UNISTR() function (or add the USING NCHAR_CS option to CHR() then it does replace those:
with cte as (
  SELECT 'H' KEY,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, UNISTR('\202d'), null), UNISTR('\202c'), null) vendor_catalog_number
  FROM MyTable LN
)
select KEY, vendor_catalog_number,
  DUMP(vendor_catalog_number, 1016) as dmp,
  RAWTOHEX(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(vendor_catalog_number)) as hex
from cte




KEY
VENDOR_CATALOG_NUMBER
DMP
HEX




H
CUR251636
Typ=1 Len=9 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 43,55,52,32,35,31,36,33,36
435552323531363336



... producing just your desired 9-character string 'CUR251636'.
fiddle
So instead of your current query:
SELECT 'H' KEY , 
REPLACE(REPLACE(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, CHR(8237), ''), CHR(8236), '') vendor_catalog_number
FROM MyTable LN

you can do:
SELECT 'H' KEY,
REPLACE(REPLACE(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, UNISTR('\202d'), null), UNISTR('\202c'), null) vendor_catalog_number
FROM MyTable LN


Thanks Alex! This data was initially inserted during a data conversion from another system so I believe that has something to do with it. Can your suggested answer be modified to not need the CTE and just run as one nested expression?

@Nick - the CTE is only there to show the value and its dump together without repeating it, you don't need it in your real code. The plain version is already in the fiddle, but I've added it to the answer too.

Great, and thank you for the detailed explanation!

Would there be an easy way to identify any other rows in this table/column where it also has this occuring?

You can query the table and filter on those characters, e.g. where instr(VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, UNISTR('\202d')) > 0.

Great, thanks again!

Just for my own curiosity, from what I can tell it looks like we relied on the XML file to know that the Unicode characters were both 202d and 202c, and then subsequently used those values in the (updated) REPLACE UNISTR function. Suppose we not had that information available from the XML, would there have been another way to see / know that?

In case you just want to get rid of those trailing characters, one possible solution is:
SELECT 'H' KEY , 
substr(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM, 2, length(LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM) - 2) vendor_catalog_number
FROM MyTable

